# Launch a function of an iPhone app from my Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, function, remote-access, watchos-3

I have an app opened  on my iPhone, I would like to know if there is a way to call remotely a function of this app from my apple-watch (watchOS 3) by simply tapping a button?

The function concerned stores data from the accelerometer.
I searched on the Internet. I found a beginning of solution on Stackoverflow  but it still remains a bit mysterious for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can transmit information from the watch app to the iOS app using the WCSession APIs. Assuming you have a paired and activated WCSession, from your watch app you can call WCSession.sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler and the message will be transmitted straight away to the iOS device. Your foreground iOS app will need to be listening for a message using WCSessionDelegate.session:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler. From there based upon the message received you can invoke your function.

Comment: Dear appfigurate,  It's a  good starting point for further investigation. Thanks a lot for your support.